# react route component is not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I created my app with create-react-app and tried to use react-router on it. but it's not working at all.
I am using react-router-dom 5.3.0 version.
But if I type page path in URL and then reload the site, components will render. Please help me out.

Here is my app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LogIn from "./Components/LogIn";
import Home from "./Components/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
      <Route  path="/"  component={Home} exact/>
      <Route  path="/login" component={LogIn}/>
      </Switch>
      </Router>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my NavBar

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import {Link  } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div className='Navbar'>
        <h3 className='title'>Mero Blog</h3>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
            <Link to='/'></Link>
        </li>
        <li className='drop'>
            Profile
            <ul className='option'>
            <li>
            <Link to='/'>See Profile</Link>
             </li>
             <li>
            <Link to='/'>Log Out</Link>
             </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <Link to='/login'>Log In</Link>
        </li>
           
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Please show your `index.js`

Comment: I have added index.js code

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your console? if so what are they

Comment: No, They are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with React18. If you change index.js to

```
    ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

then it will work but ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18.          If you have resolved this issue, please let me know.
One more thing => React 18: react-router@v5 is breaking in the Strict Mode, so without Strict Mode
Its work for me

```
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```